# Wondering how I can speed up a MySQL call

Tags: mysql

I'm looking for an answer as to how I can speed up my query on a table of 500,000 records.

I'm just inserting the `COUNT` to `BROKERAGE_STOCKS_COVERED` counting the number of times the same brokerage `ESTIMID` shows up within a date range for each record - excluding the record being examined. The only other condition is that the `ANALYST` is not blank.

I make a number of similar calls on the table - they all come back in 10 ... maybe 15 seconds. The only difference from this call and my others - is that this one returns a `COUNT` of up to 1000 for `BROKERAGE_STOCKS_COVERED` - whereas my other queries result in maybe 3, or 4 `COUNT`. This one takes almost a whole hour: :/

---

```
UPDATE `working` SET `BROKERAGE_STOCKS_COVERED` = 
    (SELECT COUNT(`ID`) 
     FROM ( SELECT `ID`, `ESTIMID`, `ANNDATS_CONVERTED`, 
                   `ANALYST`, `REVDATS_CONVERTED` 
            FROM `working`
     ) AS BB 
        WHERE 
            BB.`ANNDATS_CONVERTED` <= `working`.`ANNDATS_CONVERTED` 
        AND 
            BB.`REVDATS_CONVERTED` > `working`.`ANNDATS_CONVERTED`
        AND 
            BB.`ID` != `working`.`ID`
        AND 
            BB.`ESTIMID` = `working`.`ESTIMID`
        AND 
            BB.`ANALYST` != ''
    )
WHERE `working`.`ANALYST` != '';
```

-- 0n 500,000 rows "457656 rows affected. (Query took 2782.4304 seconds.)" (46 min)

---

```
| ID | ANALYST |   ESTIMID    | ANNDATS_CONVERTED | REVDATS_CONVERTED |  BROKERAGE_STOCKS_COVERED  | NO_TOP_RATING |  
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 1  |  DAVE   | Brokerage000 |    1998-07-01     |    1998-07-04     |                            |      3        |
| 2  |  DAVE   | Brokerage000 |    1998-06-28     |    1998-07-10     |                            |      4        |
| 3  |  DAVE   | Brokerage000 |    1998-07-02     |    1998-07-08     |                            |      2        |
| 4  |  DAVE   | Brokerage000 |    1998-07-04     |    1998-12-04     |                            |      3        |
| 5  |  SAM    | Brokerage000 |    1998-06-14     |    1998-06-30     |                            |      4        |
| 6  |  SAM    | Brokerage000 |    1998-06-28     |    1999-08-08     |                            |      4        |
| 7  |         | Brokerage000 |    1998-06-28     |    1999-08-08     |                            |      5        |
| 8  |  DAVE   | Brokerage111 |    1998-06-28     |    1999-08-08     |                            |      3        |
```

**'EXPLAIN'** results:

```
id| select_type        | table            | type  | possible_keys | key         | key_len | ref              | rows   | Extra
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1 | PRIMARY            | working          | index | ANALYST       | PRIMARY     | 4       | NULL             | 467847 | Using where
2 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | <derived3>       | ref   | <auto_key0>   | <auto_key0> | 92      | working.ESTIMID  | 46785  | Using where
3 | DERIVED            | working          | ALL   | NULL          | NULL        | NULL    | NULL             | 467847 | NULL
```

**EXPLAIN**

```
SELECT COUNT(`ID`) FROM (SELECT `ID`, `IRECCD`, `ANALYST`,  `ESTIMID`, `ANNDATS_CONVERTED`, `REVDATS_CONVERTED` FROM `working`) AS BB

id | select_type | table       | type   | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows   | Extra 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------  
1  | PRIMARY     | <derived2>  | ALL    | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 462762 | NULL
2  | DERIVED     | working     | ALL    | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 462762 | NULL
```

---

**EXPLAIN**

```
SELECT COUNT(`ID`) FROM (SELECT `ID`, `IRECCD`, `ANALYST`, `ESTIMID`, `ANNDATS_CONVERTED`, `REVDATS_CONVERTED` FROM `working`) AS BB 
WHERE 
BB.`ANNDATS_CONVERTED` <= `ANNDATS_CONVERTED` 
AND 
BB.`REVDATS_CONVERTED` > `ANNDATS_CONVERTED` 
AND 
BB.`ID` != `ID` 
AND 
BB.`ESTIMID` = `ESTIMID` 
AND 
BB.`ANALYST` != '' 

id | select_type  | table   | type  | possible_keys | key   | key_len   | ref   | rows   | Extra    
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1  | PRIMARY      |NULL     | NULL  | NULL          | NULL  |  NULL     | NULL  | NULL   | Impossible WHERE
2  | DERIVED      | working | ALL   | NULL          | NULL  | NULL      | NULL  | 462762 | NULL
```

- I think the "impossible WHERE" is just because it this part of the query is separated from the `UPDATE` for the purpose of displaying the "EXPLAIN

I am using **InnoDB** on a windows 8 PHP/MySQL install.
My columns **are indexed**. I have memory maxed on my windows/MySQL/
 and it all works great.

**- Just wondering if this is a normal wait time for such a query?**

**- And is there a way to speed this particular query up?**

Answer (score 0):

Generally - when attempting to optimize a slow running query - one would ask the database system to explain it's strategy of resolving the query.  In this case you can use the [SQL Explain command](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain.html), on the sub-select and independently and on the where clause, to find the exact cause of the slow down.  This may indicate if your where clause should exist outside the sub-select, or if the problem lies elsewhere.

Comment: I have added the 'EXPLAIN' results. Any help with what to look for here would be appreciated.

Comment: Sure! Since you didn't post the full explain input, I'll assume you were able to ask MySQL to explain the plan for the entire update state as shown above and you have acquired ~10K rows more.

The results are telling the inner most quarry (the `select ...fields... FROM working`) is effectively performing a linear scan on all rows. The where clauses in the second quarry results in a reduction of an order of magnitude in the considered rows. The third result again considers all rows within the table. I would consider removing the inner group by using `group by` or `having`.

Comment: Thanks, is it typical for a query to take this long on a table of 500000 rows?

Comment: The time consumed regarding your quarry is really a result of your the structure you have chosen.  I've seen MySQL return results in busy systems with millions of rows in the range of 10-100ms.  I've also seen bad quarries written against the same busy tables which would consume in excess of 5 minutes to run.  It looks like you are attempting to do OLAP, I would recommend attempting to normalize your data in order to speed up your quarries to reduce the quantity of data being considered if possible.

Comment: Thanks @Mark. Do you have an example of how I could "remove the inner group by using `group by`"

Comment: You would have to check this for correctness, however I believe it would be something like the following:

 (SELECT COUNT(`ID`) FROM `working`
        WHERE 
            BB.`ANNDATS_CONVERTED` <= `working`.`ANNDATS_CONVERTED` 
        AND 
            BB.`REVDATS_CONVERTED` > `working`.`ANNDATS_CONVERTED`
        AND 
            BB.`ID` != `working`.`ID`
        AND 
            BB.`ESTIMID` = `working`.`ESTIMID`
        AND 
            BB.`ANALYST` != ''
    )

This removes the inner most query which will result in all rows being loaded and considered within the query expression.